# How do we get the notation $ \||Q|\|_2=\max\{\gamma_{\max}(Q), |\gamma_{\min}(Q)|\} \, ? $

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, matrices, analysis, normed-spaces

In the textbook High-dimensional statistics, I am confused about the notation of norm of matrix. For example, consider a covariance matrix $Q$ which is symmetric. Denote its vector of eigenvalues order as
$$
\gamma_{\max}(Q)=\gamma_{1}(Q)\ge \gamma_{2}(Q)\ge \dots\ge\gamma_{d}(Q)=\gamma_{\min}(Q)
$$
I know the definition of $\ell^2$ norm of matrix $Q$ which is given by
$$
\|Q\|_{\ell^2}=\sqrt{\sum_i\sum_j |Q_{ij}|^2}
$$
But why do we have the notation?
$$
\||Q|\|_2=\max\{\gamma_{\max}(Q), |\gamma_{\min}(Q)|\}  \, ?
$$

Comment: What you are calling the $\ell_{2}$ norm of a matrix is actually the Frobenius norm.  It seems likely that you are confusing this with the 2-norm induced by the vector 2-norm which is denoted with a subscript 2.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Frobenius norm is different from $\ell_2$ norm?

Comment: Yes.  This is a source of confusion for many people especially in data science.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Ok, I see. But why add an absolute value inside the $\ell_2$ norm?

Comment: I have no idea- the notation isn't standard.

Comment: FWIW, the last formula is a correct (but uncommon) formula for the induced 2-norm of a symmetric matrix- it's exactly equivalent to the more common $\| Q \|_{2}=\sqrt{\lambda_{max}(Q^{T}Q)}$.